# Nested span elements where parent is server-side

Tags: html, asp.net, server-side-controls

In ASP.Net (4.5.2) I have nested `<span>` elements where the parent is a set as a server side control...

```
<p>
  This is the start of the text
  <span runat="server" visible="<%#someCode%>">
    This is some more Text
    <span class="myClass">with some other text inside</span>
    And a bit more after
  </span>
</p>
```

(Note, this is contained within a `<asp:Repeater>`)

It appears that ASP.Net doesn't cope with this, and appears to assume the inner `</span>` is the closure for the outer element.  Meaning that when the `visible="false"` it will render like this...

```
<p>
  This is the start of the text
    And a bit more after
  </span>
</p>
```

I cannot convert either `<span>` into a `<div>` or `<section>` as it has to live within a `<p>` element (meaning the child elements cannot be blocks).

Is there any way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK then (too many comments).

Alternatively use a `Label`:

```
<p>
    This is the start of the text
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="This is some more Text">
        <span class="myClass">with some other text inside</span>
        And a bit more after
    </asp:Label>                    
</p>
```

or even:

```
<p>
    This is the start of the text
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="true" Text="This is some more Text<span class='myClass'>with some other text inside</span>And a bit more after">                
    </asp:Label>                    
</p>
```

Comment: I was concerned that the tag within the `Text` attribute would result in a `badly formed tag` error, but it appears to also work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is quite simple... make the inner `<span>` a server-side control as well...

```
<p>
  This is the start of the text
  <span runat="server" visible="<%#someCode%>">
    This is some more Text
    <span runat="server" class="myClass">with some other text inside</span>
    And a bit more after
  </span>
</p>
```

Which results in ...

```
<p>
  This is the start of the text
</p>
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to me, now you have the overhead of another server-side control.

Comment: Yes @DavidG, I thought the same thing... but I can't figure out any other way of doing it

Comment: Does it need to be a `span`? Use a `div` or `section` or whatever.

Comment: @DavidG, as I said in the question, I can't use a `<div>` because it needs to be contained within a `<p>` element... I'll investigate `<section>`

Comment: @DavidG - nope, `<section>` acts as a block element, taking it outside of the `<p>` in the same way `<div>` does.

Comment: Then don't use a `p` tag?

Comment: @DavidG - unfortunately not possible in this current situation

Comment: So you can change span to div but not p to div? Well OK then!

Comment: @DavidG - your profile says you've been in the industry for a while (as have I) and therefore I assume you'll be aware there are times when things could be done correctly if you had the time/energy/money/enthusiasm... and there are times you just can't

Comment: Haha sure, but why is changing a single tag deemed such a time consuming or expensive operation? I suppose it doesn't matter, it's your code. :)

Comment: @DavidG - I'd tell you, but it's `TL;DR` ;-)  Thanks for your input though, it's honestly appreciated

Comment: @freefaller Interestingly enough, I am trying to reproduce but your original sample seems to work OK. (I've placed the spans inside `ItemTemplate`). So you may want to check your other markup for orphans.

Comment: Thanks @dpant but it's definitely in the block as I've described it.  Not sure I can justify much more time on this, as I do have a solution, even if it's not the best one